# What do these undocumented mobileNetworkCodes from CTCarrier mean?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-telephony

I noticed that sometimes `CTCarrier.mobileNetworkCode` returns undocumented values. Examples below:

1. "VZW" - is this Verizon?
2. "" (an empty string) instead of nil when device has no SIM card installed or in AirPlane mode - looks like a bug.
3. "65535" - kind of a special value that means something?

What do these specific undocumented codes mean?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the circumstances under which these values appear, and how you're inspecting them?

Comment: 65535 equals 0xffff or short -1. Other people have that problem too, not only on iphone, it seems to be related to sms. VZW is for verizon wireless.

Comment: @JoshCaswell My application sends stats to the server - that is where I noticed those values. "65535" was only returned by iPhone 4S so far.